# KUL-MNL-KUL - I will only use my MNL-KUL

Tags: tickets, kul, mnl

I have this concern about my KUL-MNL-KUL ticket. Can I only use my MNL-KUL ticket? Since I will be coming from Manila on the that time. Do they honor my ticket even I didn't show up on my KUL-MNL?

Comment: Alvin, short answer, you can not do that.

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot. While you are not supposed to use the KUL-MNL portion, you can get away with it and even ask for reimbursement of your unused portion. However, missing the KUL-MNL port will have the last portion voided as the airline will assume you missed the flight and cancel the remaining ticket.